#  Dictionary object performance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

I have a possible implementation scenario where I need a dictionary object that will take 3 variables. A dialect, a query name and a query string. I should note at this stage that writing a separate class object is not an option.

My question is which of the following would perform better.

A) A single dictionary object that takes the first two variables in as a composite key e.g. "dialect,queryname" and the 3rd variable as the value.

```
private Dictionary<string, string>
```

B) A dictionary object that has another dictionary object as the value so the first variable would be the key of the primary dictionary object, the 2nd variable would be the key of the 2nd dictionary object and finally the 3rd variable would be the value of the second dictionary object.

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Seems obvious but the compiler is a mysterious thing so thought I should ask you guys.

Thanks

Comment: `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`

Comment: I'm intrigued - why is writing another class not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mucking around for my own amusement ..

```
             Dictionary<string, string> md1 = new Dictionary<string,string>();
             Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> md2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

             Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

             st.Start(); 

             for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
             {
                 md1.Add(i.ToString(), "blabla"); 
             }

             st.Stop();

             Console.WriteLine(st.ElapsedMilliseconds);

             st.Reset();

             st.Start(); 

             for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
             {
                 md2.Add(i.ToString(), new Dictionary<string, string>()); 
             }

             st.Stop();

             Console.WriteLine(st.ElapsedMilliseconds);

             Console.ReadLine();
```

output:

```
831
1399
```

Comment: Nice. But you're just testing the objects creation here, not the data retrieval.

Comment: Yeah true. You could time the retrieval pretty easily tho.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're sure that the key "dialect,queryname" is unique, I think the first solution is faster. In the second one, you'd have to do one more dictionary lookup, which is probably more costly than a string concatenation.

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure that the keys will be totally unique. That was my thought but I wanted to be sure. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

I think is better than both.

Comment: You can use `Tuple<string,string>` from .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of performance, as the two have completely different semantics.

The first gives you a way to use one object to find another object.

The second gives you a way to use one object to find another object, in which you can use yet another object to find a third object.

There is slightly different functionality in terms of how these can be later extended.

Most generally, I'd use `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>`. This would give me a composite key that is clearly a composite key.

Actually, that's not true, I'd create a new class. How is that not an option? Still, if it was homework and "do not create a new class" was part of the question, I'd use `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>`.

Edit:

```
class DialectQuery : IEquatable<DialectQuery>
{
  public Dialect{get;private set}
  public Name{get;private set;}
  public DialectQuery(string dialect, string name)
  {
    Dialect = dialect;
    Name = name;
  }
  public bool Equals(DialectQuery other)
  {
    return other != null && Name == other.Name && Dialect == other.Dialect;
  }
  public override bool Equals(object other)
  {
    return Equals((object)other);
  }
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    int dHash = Dialect.GetHashCode();
    return (dHash << 16 | dHash >> 16) ^ Name.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

So far it behaves exactly the same as Tuple. Now though if I get a change request that dialects must be case-insensitive but query names case-sensitive, or that dialects are codes and therefore require invariant comparison but names are human-input and therefore require culture-aware comparison, or anything else, I've got two simple changes to make.

YAGNI doesn't apply, it's not coding a massive object "in case you need it", it's defining a good "okay, I probably don't need it, but if I do it'll go here" point.

Comment: If you were to use a class how would you structure it in order to be able to produce the same or better performance while still offering the same functionality? I need to be able to construct it and populate it with all three variables (more than one of each straight from a table in a database) and then be able to pick query strings out quickly using both key variables. To me it seems far simpler to use the first option I mention.

Comment: As a simple class with two properties and an equality override. It's half a minute's coding but nicely deals with "oh, dialects should be case-insensitive but queries shouldn't" or any other extensions that arise in the spec down the line.

Comment: How exactly would that work for my scenario? If I need to effectively produce a list of sql commands that can be accessed by two keys? The reason I want to use a dictionary object is that once populated with all the necessary dialects, query names and queries upon instantiating my sql factory class I can access whichever query I need by checking the composite key for a dialect and query name. May just be me having a slow brain day but I can't see how a class could be used to do this? All of the three variables are linked like this dialect>query name>query. How could you do that with properties